# C# MVC the proper way to construct the View with checkbox options and auto bind answer to object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view, checkboxfor

I want to make a webpage to store the user's favorite fruit(s).

here are my models:

```
public class user
{
    public long UserId {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}

public class userFruit
{
    public long UserFruitId {get; set;}
    public long UserId {get;set;}
    public long FruitId {get;set;}
}

public class Fruit
{
    public long FruitId {get;set;}
    public string FruitName {get;set;}
}
```

And i have created a linkage between **User** and **userFruit**, so that a User Object contains a List of UserFruit.

In the Controller, I will pass two things to the View:

- Model: User Model

- ViewBag: Fruit

In the View, i want to list out all Fruit from the VierBag.Fruit in CheckBox format, e.g.

- [  ] Apple

- [  ] Orange

- [  ] Banana

User is allowed to select more than one fruit.

What is the best way to implement the View so that the answer can automatically bind to the UserFruit object?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally make a `ViewModel` and have a `List<Fruit>` rather than using the `ViewBag`.

```
public class FruitViewModel
{
    public bool Apple { get; set; }
    public bool Orange { get; set; }
    public bool Banana { get; set; } 
}

public ActionResult ListFruits() 
{
   var model = new FruitViewModel();
   return View("Fruits", model);
}
```

Then in your view you can use `@Html.CheckBoxFor`

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Apple, new { id = "chkApple" });
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Orange, new { id = "chkOrange" });
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Banana, new { id = "chkBanana" });
```

These properties will then be `true` or `false` depending on the users selection and posted back up to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however the Fruit List is extensible, how can it be implemented dynamically? and moreover, how to bind the answer to the UserFruit object?